# Button does not display in browser

Tags: css, asp.net, button

I have this weird problem and I cannot pick up where is the problem!
On a specific page I just added some button with css. I can see the buttons while in normal programming mode, but the button are not visible when I run the page in debug/browser mode.

```
<td style="border: solid; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; width: 160px">
    <telerik:RadButton ID="RadButton11" runat="server" OnClick="Button11_Click" Width="100px" Height="40px" CssClass="reportN" HoveredCssClass="reportO" PressedCssClass="reportC">
    <Image EnableImageButton="true" />
    </telerik:RadButton>
</td>
```

---

```
.reportN {
    background: url('../pictures/reportN.png') center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}

.reportO {
    background: url('../pictures/reportO.png') center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}

.reportC {
    background: url('../pictures/reportC.png') center;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

---

```
protected void Button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Response.Redirect("~/members/ReportMissMat.aspx");
}
```

This is in programming mode
[image]

This is in debug/browser mode
[image]

Can some one give me a hint? Is there anything wrong that is causing the button not to display?

Comment: is the path of the image correct?

Comment: @FeliceM: Can you check the display property of button. And is it possible to give an running example in fiddle

Comment: @Alek, yes it is. Otherwise would not even display in programming mode.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page or are you running locally?

Comment: @Obsidion, it i all local for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your css:

**CSS**

```
.reportN {
    display:block;
}
.reportO {
    display:block;
}
.reportC {
    display:block;
}
```

- The button is likely displaying: as 0px height and width.
- This happens because the button has no content.
- The background image do not provide block level rendering.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try clearing the cashe. With most browsers that's ctrl+f5.